# Why select2 filter function doesn't work when i take the options from json

Tags: jquery-select2

Halo, i'm new to javascript, i'm using select2, i take the options from desproducts.php which return json containing product list. The product list is shown, but the filter function doesn't work, here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0UeO.png)

here is my code :

```
$('.select2-show-search').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: '',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'desproducts.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
            };
        },
      }
});
```

---

i have found a sloution, i take the options directly from database using this code :

```
<select class="form-control select2-show-search">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach ($desproducts as $desproduct): ?>
    <option value="<?= $desproduct["desProductID"] ?>" harga="<?= 
     $desproduct["desProductPrice"] ?>"><?= $desproduct["desProductName"] ?> 
    </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

and this is the code in javascript

```
$('.select2-show-search').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: '',
    allowClear: true,
});
```

Comment: could you show your data?

Comment: hello @Frenchy, I have found a solution, I change my method to take the options, thanks for your reply